# Temporary variables in Excel formulas

Tags: excel

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),-4,2+MATCH(MIN(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,3,1,10)), OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,3,1,10), 0),1,1)
```

in the above example (don't consider what it does), I have to evaluate twice the exact same expression : `OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,3,1,10)`

Is there a way to add variables on the fly in formulas? So that we store once the result and simply refer to it later on within the formula ? This is an example in which the cost of computing several times the same thing has no impact, but what about more costly calls or computations ?

I'm thinking of some feature that are existing in recursive functional languages such as Caml.

Comment: Can't you use other cells for temporary variables? If it makes your sheet ugly, then you could also hide them.

Comment: Actuaylly, no, you can't "store variables" within pure Excel formulas. As weston pointed out, the only way is to use intermediate cells.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there such things as variables within an Excel formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace Indirect(address(row(),Column()) with a simple relative cell reference, but to answer your question:

yes it is possible using Laurent Longre's MOREFUNC addin - it has functions SETV and GETV that do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Charles, the following website states that Laurent Longre's 
addin is no longer maintained http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html . Do you by any chance know if there are more recent addins with similar functionalities?

Comment: My commercial product SpeedTools http://www.decisionmodels.com/fastexcelv3speedtools.htm has some functions similar to MoreFunc functions, but for the equivalent to SETV and GETV - SETMEM and GETMEM the performance improvements have not proved significant in most cases because the overhead of handling multi-threaded calc for these funcs tends to offset the speed gains.

Answer (score 4):

9 years later, this is possible!

If you have Microsoft 365, you can use "LET" to define a temporary variable.

Eg =LET(MyTempVar, 2, MyTempVar + 3) would be a really bad way to calculate 2 + 3 = 5.

In your case, you'd do

=LET(**MyTempVar**, OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,3,1,10), ***formula***)

Answer (score 3):

If your question relates to the convenience of writing formulas, the Name Manager is what you're looking for. See in the ribbon menu in the tab "formulas". Click on "new"

> Name: MyArray
>
> Scope: Workbook
>
> Refers to: =OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,3,1,10)

If your question relates to computation cost, I believe your only solution is to physically store the intermediate results in an additional column or separate worksheet.