# Excel - Shortest function to return index or false otherwise

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for the shortest function (to replace c2) to look for instance of text in a cell and returns index when found and false/0 if not.

The required formula must not repeat the find part.

Consider:

```
cell a2: the quick brown fox
cell c2: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("a",A2)),FIND("a",A2),FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought excel could not do what you want.

See the following thread for more information:

[Are there such things as variables within an Excel formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula/771981#771981)

But I think you can use:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("a", A2),"False")
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(FIND("a", A2),0)
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to see an index be returned when found too.

Comment: what do you mean by "INDEX", I was assuming you meant the number returned by FIND? Derek's suggestion will return the position, if found, otherwise FALSE

Comment: Yes - the number returned by FIND.

Comment: The suggested formula will do that - with IFERROR the result of the first argument is returned....unless it returns an error in which case the second argument is returned - it was specifically introduced in Excel 2007 to avoid the need for repetition

Comment: I'm looking for a formula, if it's possible, to not repeat the **FIND("a",A2)** part.

Comment: Derek, has given you that - `=IFERROR(FIND("a", A2),FALSE)` - If A2 contains "hat" that will give you the position of the "a" [2] - if A2 contains "hot" the result will be FALSE because "a" does not appear in A2 - isn't that what you need? - did you try it, which version of excel are you using?