# Is it possible to declare a variable within formula and using it into same formula in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big excel formula like-

```
=CONCATENATE(  IF(  AND(LEN(A1)>3,LEN(A1)>=5),CONCATENATE( VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,5),2)),rng,2)," হাজার "),IF( AND(LEN(A1)>3,LEN(A1)=4),CONCATENATE( VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),1)),rng,2)," হাজার "),"")),IF(LEN(A1)>2,IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3),1))>0,CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3),1)),rng,2),"শত "),""),""),IF(NUMBERVALUE(IF(LEN(A1)>1, RIGHT(A1,2), RIGHT(A1,1)))>0,VLOOKUP( NUMBERVALUE(IF(LEN(A1)>1, RIGHT(A1,2), RIGHT(A1,1))),rng,2,FALSE),""))
```

In this formula I had to use 'A1' reference again and again.
I need a function or anything like this-

```
=DEFVAR(A1,'somevar',CONCATENATE(  IF(  AND(LEN(somevar)>3,LEN(somevar)>=5),CONCATENATE(....)
```

So that I can use the formula on 'M9' cell like this-

```
=DEFVAR(M9,'somevar',CONCATENATE(  IF(  AND(LEN(somevar)>3,LEN(somevar)>=5),CONCATENATE(....)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you use `AND(LEN(A1)>3,LEN(A1)>=5)` ? You could simply use `LEN(A1)>=5` instead.

Comment: Why do you use `AND(LEN(A1)>3,LEN(A1)=4)`? You could simply use `LEN(A1)=4` instead. In that case, you would have seen immediately that you could have replaced `LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),1)` by `LEFT(A1,1)`.

Comment: Why do you use `IF(LEN(A1)>1, RIGHT(A1,2), RIGHT(A1,1))` twice? In both cases, you could have simply used `RIGHT(A1,2)` instead.

Comment: @PeterPesch There may be  many ways of optimizing/minimizing the formula. But, for now that is not my concern. I need a reusable variable like I said in the example. Better consider it an example. Thanks.

Comment: If you really need that same formula over and over again, maybe you should ask someone to make a custom function (in excel-vba) for you.

Comment: @PeterPesch I know vba and easily can do that. But, is it possible to do without vba. i.e. define a var=A1 at the beginning of the formula and use the var later instead of A1 in the same formula?

Comment: Apparently not: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I'm going for vba then.

Comment: If the idea is to change the cell that is repeatedly referenced, you could use the Indirect function to store the cell name in a different cell, but that is as close as you can come to a "variable" in a formula.

Comment: Did someone tell microsoft that I wanted this!?
They are making LAMBDA, and almost done!
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/lambda-the-ultimatae-excel-worksheet-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Excel formulas don't allow you to declare variables within them.

But what you *could* do in this case is use another cell that holds `LEN(A1)`, and use that in your formula. Excel's very clever calculation cycle will guarantee that `LEN(A1)` is evaluated before any dependent formulas.

Essentially then you are using one or more other cells to hold "variables".

This also makes your spreadsheet easier to maintain. Avoid VBA if you can; (1) it's difficult to version-control, (2) not all companies permit use of `.xlsm` due to security issues, (3) VBA runs in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic quetion is, *"declare variable within formula and use it into the same formula".*

Answer is NO.

Any Formula in Excel doesn't allows to declare variable and use it further. This is a common practice while programming and needless to say how, since somewhere you have written that you are using VBA!.

**Now let me tell you how indirectly we use variables in Excel formula.**

*It's a Cell address which works as a variable. Other is Named Range which carries more than one value like an Array. Further more you can also use a formula as variable*.

*Let me say how, write a formula in cell and just Name it and use that Name in any formula like we call procedure while programming. A simple example I'm showing you here*.

Write formula is A2, = if(A5>=1000,Max(B2:B100),0) and just Name it like MYMAX. Then in other formula you can call it like, =if(B2 = "A01",MYMAX,"Nothing").

**Hope this help you to realize that, why we need Programming.**