# Subtract amount if outcome is above threshold, without duplicate formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a lengthy formula F and want to subtract amount A if outcome of F is > A. Else the function should return the value of the formula.

I can just write out straightforward (pseudo code)

```
= IF ((F()>A), F()-A, F())
```

Drawback is that I have to write out formula F() three times. If the formula changes, I have to patch it on three locations. 
Ideally, I would have a temporary result-value like this (pseudo code)

```
= LET $X = F(); IF (($X>A), $X-A, $X)
```

Of course I can do that with storing the outcome of F() in an extra cell, but I am searching for an elegant solution, all in just 1 cell.

Comment: using helper columns may not look as pretty as single cell results, but trying to maintain a spreadsheet that has monstrous and complex formula in a single cell can be a nightmare.  By breaking a formula down and using multiple columns/rows to simplify your formulas and show steps in the process will make maintaining/editing of the spreadsheet in the future much easier

Comment: The answer below is your best bet using standard formula, there is no method in standard formula to save a variable, outside of using a helper cell.  You could write a UDF in vba that allows only the one entry.

Answer (score 1):

I have an option to reduce it from three times to only two:

`= F() - IF ((F()>A), A, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

The same problem was already discussed here on SO. (I did check for it when posting, but did not find it then.)
So I consider this question answered. (Spoiler: VLOOKUP helps, but costs extra cell too)  Thanks AbdelAziz and Forward Ed.
[Are there such things as variables within an Excel formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula)

Comment: You are welcome.